# Integrating my asp.net mvc web application with a Java based open source BPM (Business Process Management) software

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc-3, open-source, integration

My company employees have good knowledge and experience in developing asp.net web application especially using the MVC framework. And  I need to buy an open source java based BPM solution which will provide the base engine for the BPM software my team will be developing.

But my question is if it possible  to integrate the open source  Java-based BPM software with an asp.net MVC web application that we are going to build on top of the java based BPM engine?
BR

Comment: ,Would you mind telling your result and solution ? I need to choose a bpms core for develop by .net but I can not make a decision?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your MVC application exposes web services (REST or SOAP) the BPM engine can communicate with it.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but why should i should expose web services to integrate with the BPM ,,, I think the situation is that the BPM already have a REST API that i can integrate with without the need to have web services on my asp.net mvc web application,, for example same as integrating with Google maps API i can call the API using REST even if my application does not expose web services? am i right ???

Comment: Google are service providers so they expose an API for you (as a client) to use. BPM helps you connect existing **services** together. So if you have a SAP system and some other accounting system and you want them to trade data, you will expose an interface to each as a web service and the BPM will manage the workflow by utilizing the exposed interfaces.